# Angular different behaviour in IE11 and Chrome when using transclude and disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a simple transclude directive

```
 app.directive('trans', function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        template: '<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
      }
  })
```

And If I use directive like this:

```
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="data.test" placeholder="outside" />
  <trans disabled="true">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="data.test" placeholder="inside" />
  </trans>
```

Then behaviour is acting different on IE11 and Chrome.

In chrome disabled is ignored.

In IE field looks like disabled but you can type in it and placeholder is preserved and you cannot use delete button, only backspace.

My question is why ? And what behaviour is correct ? Is it bug in Angular or in IE or in Chrome ?

Thank you

example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/DRzrXABCQheQEpa51dJj?p=preview